# Can't get Discussion Form Update to run

Tags: module, forum, updating, discussion

I'm attempting to upgrade my EE Discussion Form Module from version 3.1.8 to 3.1.14 in my EE 2.7.3 environment. I followed the upgrade instructions, but when I access the `Add-ons > Modules > Discussion Forum` page in the CP nothing happens. The module doesn't seem to update. The only odd thing I see is that the change log for the module shows entries for 3.1.5 and then jumps to 3.1.14. There doesn't seem to be version 3.1.6 - 3.1.13 and I'm on version 3.1.8. So could the issue be that the module update scripts aren;t recognizing my version as one available for upgrade?

Answer (score 0):

And once again it seems I was a bit too quick to post a question. I was able to force the update to run my clicking the `Run Module Updates` button on the Modules page. So I guess the follow up questions would be Why? and Shouldn't accessing the modules control panel page still triggered the update?

Comment: No visiting the add-on page won't ever trigger the Run Module Updates trigger. Some add-ons instruct you to do that, like with Playa, in order to update but visiting the module page generally will have nothing to do with the update process.

Comment: Visiting the modules listing page will not automatically try to update them all, but visiting the module's own page triggers any available updates.